# register_shutdown_function and mail()

Tags: php, email

I am using some software that sends e-mails via a call to `mail()` within a function that is called via `register_shutdown_function`.
This seemed to work for a while, but recently `mail()` has started returning `FALSE` every time. The same call to `mail()` succeeds when called from a normal context.

Is there some sort of server settings or module that could be causing this issue?
My web hoster is unfortunately not being very helpful about this.

I am using PHP 5.3.26 (apache2handler) with the following extensions:

> Core, PDO, Phar, Reflection, SPL, SQLite, SimpleXML, Zend Guard
>   Loader, apache2handler, apc, bcmath, bz2, calendar, ctype, curl, date,
>   dba, dbase, dom, ereg, exif, fileinfo, filter, ftp, gd, geoip,
>   gettext, hash, iconv, imagick, imap, intl, ionCube Loader, json, ldap,
>   libxml, mbstring, mcrypt, mhash, ming, mysql, mysqli, openssl, pcre,
>   pdf, pdo_mysql, pdo_sqlite, posix, pspell, session, shmop, soap,
>   sockets, sqlite3, standard, suhosin, sysvmsg, sysvsem, sysvshm, tidy,
>   tokenizer, wddx, xml, xmlreader, xmlrpc, xmlwriter, xsl, zip, zlib

Could `suhosin` be causing problems here?

Comment: Does sending email by a normal mail() call work?

Comment: Yes. The same call to mail() succeeds when called from a normal context.

Comment: Can you share some sourcecode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else runs into this problem: The issue was caused by the shutdown function being called from a different context in which the execution directory was different from the normal /www directory. The solution was to add a `chdir('xxx')` before the call to `mail()` to change back to the www directory.

Comment: `mail()` couldn't care less about working directory. You possibly have some other code that attempts to load a file or execute a command using relative paths.

Comment: I don't know why but this is definitely the issue. I have a test case where I do nothing but call mail() from inside a function. Without the chdir() this fails, with the chdir() it works. I suspect this may be related to some weird security settings on my hoster's side, but I am not sure.